# Would two species of yeast with similar genome sizes have the same number of genes or chromosomes?

Tags: cell-biology, microbiology, chromosome, genetics, genomes

Similar organisms generally have similar genome sizes. Given this, would two species of yeast have the same number of genes and chromosomes?

Edit: Fixed with thanks to @daniel-standage

Comment: I'm doubtful regarding your premise. See my related comment on [this thread](http://biology.stackexchange.com/a/3468/43).

Answer (score 3):

This question appears to start from the premise that different species of yeast are closely related, but they aren't. *Saccharomyces cerevisae* and *Schizosaccharomyces pombe*, both Ascomycetes, are thought to have diverged at least 300 million years ago (c.f. the mammalian divergence from other vertebrates was about 200 million years ago).

[*S. cerevisiae*](http://www.yeastgenome.org/cache/genomeSnapshot.html) has a genome size of 12.1 Mb, with 5821 protein coding genes (plus another 786 dubious ORFs) spread over 16 chromosomes.

[*S. pombe*](http://www.pombase.org/status/statistics) has a genome size of 12.6 Mb with 5124 protein coding genes on just 3 chromosomes.

Filamentous fungi have larger genomes and gene numbers. From memory, *Aspergillus nidulans* has 8 chromosomes and over 9,000 protein coding genes. So, the similarity in gene numbers in the two yeasts probably reflects their broadly similar lifestyles.